# Finding union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was given the family F$_n$ = $\{\frac{1}{k}\mid k,n\in \mathbb{Z}^+,k\ge n\}$

As stated in title, I need to find union and intersection of this family. I am pretty sure written out this family would be

F1=1,1/2,1/3.....

F2=1/2,1/2,1/4...

and so on

but when I gave the answers of union=(0, infinity) and intersection=(0) I was wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT.**

**Union:** Notice that $F_1$ consists of all the fractions of the form $1/n$, where $n \geq 1$, $F_2$ constsists of all the fractions of the from $1/n$, where $n \geq 2$, etc.. So is $F_2 \subset F_1$? Is $F_3 \subset F_2$? Continue this. What set are all the $F_n$'s contained in? What set does this make their union?

**Intersection:** I think you either have the correct answer or the spirit of it. If you meant the intersection was $\{0\}$, then this is not correct. Is $0$ in any of the $F_n$'s considering the $F_n$'s consist of positive rational numbers? If $0$ is in none of them, can it be in their intersection? With this possibility eliminated and given you seemed to have eliminated all the other rationals, what must the intersection then be?

Comment: So the Union would be Fn+1⊂Fn and intersection would be null?

Comment: The union is exactly $F_1$. Notice $F_n \subset F_1$ since the sets are what called nested (meaning, the next set is contained in the previous set), so once you union them all the $F_n$ are not adding anything that is not already in $F_1$.  What I was getting at was $\cdots F_n \subset F_{n-1} \subset \cdots \subset F_3 \subset F_2 \subset F_1$. So their union is $F_1$. [In fact, maybe think about why if $A$ is a subset of a set $X$, then prove $X \cup A=X$ always.]  You are now correct about the intersection.

Comment: oh wow, I was overthinking this problem way too much. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @George Glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer if you wanted. Best of luck with your studies!

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the intersection, but not the union. Can you get values greater than 1? Can you get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?.